# How can I create a delay during a DoubleAnimation when using AutoReverse?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, animation, doubleanimation

I have an animation which moves a grid to a specific place and then automatically goes back using AutoReverse. But since it's instant the user cannot read the message inside of it. How can I put a -for example- 5 seconds delay in the animation

Here is the method I have so far

```
public void ErrorMessage(Grid grid, ImageSource imageSource, String error_message)
    {
        Image_Broken_Component.Source = imageSource;
        TextBlock_Error_Message.Text = error_message;

        ThicknessAnimation ta = new ThicknessAnimation
        {
            From = grid.Margin,
            To = new Thickness(0, 50, 0, 0),
            Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)),
            AutoReverse = true
        };
        grid.BeginAnimation(Grid.MarginProperty, ta);
    }
```

The animation should play like this (using the From and To-values): 1 -> 0 -> wait 5s -> 1

Comment: Instead of AutoReverse, run a second animation with a specific BeginTime from a Completed handler of the first one. Or when the user clicks into the notification to confirm they have noticed it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the `AutoReverse` property, use a `Storyboard`:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/graphics-multimedia/storyboards-overview

The `BeginTime` property can be used to delay the second animation to do basic sequencing as seen here:

[XAML C# WPF Best efficient way to do an ordered sequence of animations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2486646/xaml-c-sharp-wpf-best-efficient-way-to-do-an-ordered-sequence-of-animations)

Then you can just sequence two `ThicknessAnimations` (one forward, one reverse) and set the `BeginTime` of the second one so that there is a pause before the animation is reversed.

Example code:

```
public void ErrorMessage(Grid grid, ImageSource imageSource, String error_message)
{
    Image_Broken_Component.Source = imageSource;
    TextBlock_Error_Message.Text = error_message;

    var storyboard = new Storyboard();

    storyboard.Children.Add(new ThicknessAnimation
    {
        From = grid.Margin,
        To = new Thickness(0, 50, 0, 0),
        Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))
    });

    storyboard.Children.Add(new ThicknessAnimation
    {
        From = new Thickness(0, 50, 0, 0),
        To = grid.Margin,
        Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)),
        BeginTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(6)
    });

    grid.BeginStoryboard(Grid.MarginProperty, storyboard);
}
```